# Autofill a Cell in a uitable - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

I have a comment field in a uitable that I wish to autofill based on other comments entered previously in the same column. Is it possible to program it in Matlab without using Java?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `'CellEditCallback'` of the `uitable`. The code you write there (such as a function call) is executed whenever the value of a cell is edited.

Here's an example, which updates the last column with the sum of the other two.

```
t = uitable('Data', [10 30 40], 'ColumnName', {'Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Sum'}, ...
    'ColumnEditable', [true true false], 'Position', [20 20 260 100]);
set(t, 'CellEditCallback', ...
    'd = get(gcbo, ''Data''); set(gcbo, ''Data'', [d(1:end-1) sum(d(1:end-1))])')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. As I use the table in GUI & I will add the function inside the CellEditCallback as suggested. What is the command that store/read/access the previous comments in the same column?

Comment: It depends on your specific case, but you should probably access the `’Data’` property of the `uitable`, as in my example

Comment: I tried set(handles.infoTable, 'CellEditCallback', ...
    'd = get(gcbo, ''Data''); set(gcbo, ''Data'', [])') and it does not work as it clear the uitable. Why?

Comment: I don’t know, sorry. A minimal example with runnable code would be needed